What does the で mean in 限りで?
What does the で mean in this sentence?:
''そうだな 見てる限りではなんともなさそうだったな''
Direct translation/meaning if possible


そうだな、見てる限りではなんともなさそうだったな

If we take 限り to mean "extent", (Verb + 限り) means "the extent that (I) ". It's often paired with forms of 見る to mean "to the extent that I see", or more naturally, "as far as I can tell / see". So the above sentence, in natural English, could be:
"Right, as far as I can tell it wasn't a big deal."
The で (often paired with は) is forming the "as" or "to the" in "to the extent that...". It's optional here and could have been dropped from the sentence.
